# Code shared between virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods

There is an abstract class A which has a pure virtual member function func(). A great number of derived classes are present, each one with a different implementation of func().

Imagine now that you want to add an extra task to be carried out at each call of func(), let's say a `cout << "hello world";` independently from the derived class. The task is also independent from the content of func() so it could be executed before, after or even in the middle of func(), only the fact that it gets executed once each call to func() matters.

Does c++(11) allow a smart way to do this?

The best thing that comes to my mind is to write a pre-func() method in the parent class where the task is implemented and copy a call to pre-func() at the beginning of all the func() implementations in the derived classes. Anything better?

Comment: What you are describing is called, "Template Method". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @AdamBurry Thanks, I was sure this could't be the first time in the history that this issue appears :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could use the [Non-virtual interface idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface)

You'd have the base class as follow:

```
class A{

public:
    void myFunc();

private:
    virtual void myVirtualFunc();
}
```

with notably the following in the .cpp :

```
void A::myFunc(){
    //stuff
    myVirtualFunc();
    //stuff
}
```

Then each derived class can reimplement `myVirtualFunc()` and change its behavior. The virtual is private so you're guaranteed it won't be called anywhere but in the public non-virtual defined by the base class (guaranteeing that the code you need to run for each call will be ran), and the private visibility doesn't prevent the derived class from reimplementing it. The derived class can specify what the virtual does, not where (though as mentioned by @WhozCraig, the derived class still can reimplement the virtual function as public).

Comment: Outside of C++ the non-virtual interface idiom is known as the [*Template Method Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: The base `private:` declaration doesn't prevent the derived class from redeclaring access as `public:`, so the protection you speak of is only if you're accessing the object through an `A` pointer or reference. There is nothing stopping you from declaring `Derived::myFunc()` to be `public:` and still *virtual*. [See it live](http://ideone.com/EBRxlU). Therefore, outside of an `A&` or `A*`, no such guarantee exists.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight As this was tagged C++, I'd thought I'd use the term related to the language (but you're right!).

Comment: Yep! This is the kind of smartness I was thinking about, many thanks also for the alacrity!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly one option available to you is to create the "pre-func()" method in the base class and have that function print "Hello World" and then call "func()". That way your derived classes all override "func()" but you invoke the API through "pre-func()" (obviously I wouldn't use the term pre-func as it no longer describes the functionality accurately)